# Measuring upload/download performance of storage folders

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm investigating performance problems of an application of ours which downloads objects from google storage. The problems seem to affect only objects downloaded from certain folders and not from others, so I was guessing that those folders are served by a google node which is being slow for some reason.

I tried `gsutil perfdiag` to prove/disprove this idea, but it measures the performance of an entire bucket. Is there existing tooling to do a test with the granularity of a single folder?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-d` parameter to check for a directory.

```
-d  Sets the directory to store temporary local files in. If not specified, a default temporary directory will be used.
```

You could also check the if the bucket you're trying to work on is Regional or Multi-Regional if that helps you to encapsulate the idea of latency. A Regional bucket will stick to a region and will not be replicated as a Multi-Regional bucket.